# What would be the mirror equation of a Brier curve?

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation

The Brier equation gives a right skewed humped curve (i.e. long left tail and right skew to the curve),given by the equation `y = q*X (X - Xnot) * sqrt(Xmax - X)`.
I need a "horizontally flipped" version of the curve, with a left skewed humped curve (i.e. long right tail and left skew to the curve). How to modify this equation to obtain that?

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand your equations if you used mathjax. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: More information required in the question. (i) the formula you give doesn't seem to match any of the Brier score formulas in Wikipedia - where is your definition from? (ii) what are you doing this to achieve? I don't think it will have the same interpretation as a Brier score (iii) Flipped about what point?